# Adding Bind to a prototyped object in vanilla Javascript in a for loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a Javascript class with a prototyped method that is using a for loop to add an event listener to a group of objects and calling another method in the class.

In order to be able to access the other method in the class I have to bind the function in the event listener that gives me access to the other class method.  However I always get the highest value in the for loop so I return a function in an anonymous function, but now I can't get the bind function to work and find the other class method.

```
    ToDoList.prototype = {
      addListener : function(){
        //inside for loop
        for(var i = 0; i < ToDoList.counter; i++){
          el.addEventListener("click", ((function(value){               
            return function(){ 
              this.remove(value); //trying to call this method
            };
            })(i)).bind(this)               
          );
        }

      }

      remove : function(index){
        //do some stuff if you can get to me         
      }
    }
```

The code above only works on the last value of the for loop.  Is there any way that I can get the code to work on all the values in the for loop.

Comment: What `for` loop ?

Comment: its in a for loop I just omitted for simplicity

Comment: Okay, I just changed your code for simplicity -> https://jsfiddle.net/4onwcf3n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function returns a new function with `this` set to the first argument of `bind`, and all subsequent arguments are passed as parameters.

You don't need a closure if using `bind`:

```
ToDoList.prototype = {
  addListener: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ToDoList.counter; i++) {
      el.addEventListener("click", function(value) {
        // `this` is the same as outer `this`
        // `value` is `i`
        this.remove(value);
      }.bind(this, i));
    }
  },
  remove: function(index) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES2015 features:

```
ToDoList.prototype = {
  addListener() {
    for (let i = 0; i < ToDoList.counter; i++) {
      el.addEventListener("click", () => this.remove(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Neat huh?

The `let` will make it so that each iteration of the loop has its own `i`, rather than a shared one for the entire function. That solves the problem of `i` being equal to `ToDoList.counter`.

The arrow function `=>` is automatically bound, so you don't need to worry about `this`, it'll automatically be bound to the external `this` correctly.